# Component not updating on props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to re-render a component based on update to the props from its parent. But unless I use forceUpdate() I cant get the component to re-render on its own.

This is the component where I am updating the component and passing it to the child component:

```
var StoryContainer = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        currentItem: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
    },

    componentWillMount: function(){
        metrics.currentItem = 0;
        metrics.nextItem = 2;
    },

    handleClick: function(ctx){
        metrics.currentItem++;
        metrics.nextItem++;

        var data = this.props.data.slice(metrics.currentItem, metrics.nextItem);
        data[0].idx = metrics.currentItem
        data[1].idx = metrics.nextItem - 1;
        console.log(ctx);
        ctx.props.data = data;
        ctx.props.idx = metrics.currentItem;
        // this.forceUpdate();
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <StoryItems data={this.props.data.slice(metrics.currentItem,metrics.nextItem)} onChange={this.handleClick} />
        )   
    }
});
```

This is the class to which I am passing the updated props.

```
var StoryItems = React.createClass({
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
        console.log(nextProps);
    },
    componentWillMount: function(a){
        console.log('StoryItems:componentWillMount', a);
    },
    componentDidMount: function(a){
        console.log('StoryItems:componentDidMount', a);
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps){
        console.log('StoryItems:shouldComponentUpdate', nextProps);
        return true;
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                <Story data={this.props.data[1]} onChange={this.handleItemUnmount} />
                <Story data={this.props.data[0]} onChange={this.handleItemUnmount} />
            </View>
        );
    },
    handleItemUnmount: function(ctx){
        // console.log('here', ctx);
        this.props.onChange(this);
    },

});

module.exports = StoryItems;
```

Can anyone spot something wrong? React n00b here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `StoryContainer.handleClick` is called, nothing is done to tell React that you need to re-render `StoryContainer`, which is what sends new props to `StoryItems`. You are mutating the `metrics` variable which React doesn't know about, so React won't know to re-render anything.

You should keep the `metrics` variable as `state` on the `StoryContainer` component, and then update that with `setState`. The call to `setState` on `StoryContainer` will tell React to re-render it (since its state has changed) and that will pass new props to `StoryItems`.